# Inherting and overriding bean properties of same bean id in module project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, overriding, spring-bean

My question is about which configuration strategy I should use for my Java Spring application which runs multiple threads in a clustered environment.

The hierarchy of the application is like this:

```
Main application files & config
|
|__Parent module files & config
   |
   |__Child module files & config
```

I have a DataProvider which is @Transactional:

```
@Transactional
public class DataProvider {

    protected Configuration configuration;

    public DataProvider(Configuration configuration, DummyArg1 arg1, DummyArg2 arg2) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        createResult();
        addMoreStuffFromModules();
    }

    private void createResult() {
        this.result.setSomeStuff = "someStuff";
    }

    private void addMoreStuffFromModules() {
        this.result.setSomeMoreStuff = configuration.getModuleDataProvider.getData();
    }
}
```

Main application configuration:

```
<bean id="dataProvider" abstract="true" class="com.main.DataProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="main-configuration"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="main-dummyArg1"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="main-dummyArg2"/>
</bean

<bean id="main-Configuration" class="com.main.Configuration" /> <!-- just an empty class in main application -->
```

Parent module configuration:

```
<bean id="dataProvider" abstract="true" class="com.main.DataProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="parent-configuration"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="parent-dummyArg1"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="main-dummyArg2"/>
</bean

<bean id="parent-Configuration" class="com.parent.Configuration" />
```

As you can see. Parent module needs to provide new bean for dataProvider and all constructor arguments to be able to inject its own configuration into the Data Provider class.
This is the same for the child module:

```
<bean id="dataProvider" abstract="true" class="com.main.DataProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="child-configuration"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="parent-dummyArg1"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="main-dummyArg2"/>
</bean

<bean id="child-Configuration" class="com.child.Configuration" />
```

Is this a good strategy? I think it's not. Because what happens if the parent configuration updates (for example sets configuration to reference another bean)? Then we would want the child configuration to automatically get that new reference in the constructor-arg.

I would prefer if its possible, to have the configuration for the modules only set the constructor args as they want to change (not the other args), for example like this:

```
<bean id="dataProvider" abstract="true" class="com.main.DataProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="child-configuration"/>
        <!-- arg1 inherited from parent and/or main configuration -->
        <!-- arg2 inherited from parent and/or main configuration-->
</bean

<bean id="child-Configuration" class="com.child.Configuration" />
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `Configuration` a bean, you can just override that bean in the child modules and simply not override the `DataProvider` bean.

**Update**

Java based configuration example, as I don't use XML configs:

Suppose you have 3 beans that DataProvider needs:

```
@Component
public class Configuration {
    // main config here
}

@Component
public class OtherData {
}

@Component
public class MoreData {
}
```

And a Data provider like this:

```
@Component
public class DataProvider {
    @Inject private Configuration conf;
    @Inject private OtherData otherData;
    @Inject private MoreData moreData;
}
```

Then in your other module do:

```
@Component @Primary
public class ChildConfiguration extends Configuration {
    // different config here
}
```

... and you will have overriden only the Configuration part without changing the other two parts.

Comment: I do not fully understand. Can you add an example?

Comment: Does the @Component annotation work out of the box? Or do I need to enable annotation-scanning somehow?

Comment: how about if both parent module and child module wants to override configuration? Can they both provide @Primary in their classes? If so which one will be chosen?

Comment: @Primary can only be used once per bean per spring context.  You should either make seperate applications or you could use a request scoped configuration (which means that when a request comes in, you determine which configuration is needed and set that one up before calling anything that needs DataProvider).

Comment: Make a separate application is not in the reasonable scope. Request scoped config is too expensive. The config must be loaded at startup for performance reasons. Too bad